# wxWidget mouse processing

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I use wxWidget-3.1.4 under windows 10
I try to process mouse events from my class.
Header class:

```
#include "wx/wxprec.h"
#include <wx/wfstream.h>


class MainWindow : public wxFrame
{
public:
   MainWindow(const wxString& title);

   void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
   void OnOpenImage(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED);
   void OnEditImage(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED);

   //will redirect mouse event to class ImageDrawing
   void OnMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent& event);
   void OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event);
   void OnMouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event);
   void OnMouseUp(wxMouseEvent& event);
private:
   //wx Panel for drawing image
   wxPanel* m_background;
   wxImage* m_Image;
 ...
};
```

Cpp file:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    m_background = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    m_background->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MainWindow::OnPaint, this);
}
void MainWindow::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    Close(true);
}

void MainWindow::OnOpenImage(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxString file = OpenFileDialog("Open Image file", "png files (*.png)|*.png");
    openImage(file, true);
}

void MainWindow::OnEditImage(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxString file = OpenFileDialog("Open Image file", "png files (*.png)|*.png");
    // some logic
}
void MainWindow::OnMouseWheel(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    std::cout<<"OnMouseWheel(event)";
}
void MainWindow::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    std::cout<<"OnMouseMove(event)";
}
void MainWindow::OnMouseDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    std::cout<<"OnMouseDown(event)";
}
void MainWindow::OnMouseUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    std::cout<<"OnMouseUp(event)";
}
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MainWindow, wxFrame)
EVT_MENU(Minimal_Quit, MainWindow::OnQuit)
EVT_MENU(Open_Image, MainWindow::OnOpenImage)
EVT_MENU(Edit_Image, MainWindow::OnEditImage)

EVT_MOTION(MainWindow::OnMouseMove)
EVT_MOUSEWHEEL(MainWindow::OnMouseWheel)
EVT_LEFT_DOWN(MainWindow::OnMouseDown)
EVT_LEFT_UP(MainWindow::OnMouseUp)
EVT_RIGHT_DOWN(MainWindow::OnMouseDown)
EVT_RIGHT_UP(MainWindow::OnMouseUp)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()
```

the problem is that event menu works fine, also OnMouseWheel works, but all other mouse events are not working. Googling problem shows that a reason for this is because a parent component, in my case wxFrame is included some child, like wxPanel, and this child component could intercept events.
So why OnMouseWheel is working and all other is not. the same behaviour if I change wxFrame to wxPanel in event table and if I didn't use m_background.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by applying the following changes in constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    m_background = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    m_background->Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &MainWindow::OnPaint, this);
    m_background->Connect(wxEVT_MOTION, wxMouseEventHandler(MainWindow::OnMouseMove));
    m_background->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, wxMouseEventHandler(MainWindow::OnMouseDown));
    m_background->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, wxMouseEventHandler(MainWindow::OnMouseUp));
}
```

in each function that if you want to access to some class member or parameter you need to do the following:

```
void MainWindow::OnMouseMove(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    MainWindow* pointer = dynamic_cast<MainWindow*>(this->GetParent());
    if(pointer->m_path.size() > 0)
        pointer->m_drawing->OnMove(event);
}
```

and instead of **this**, you need to use a **pointer**, the reason for this because **this** now point to m_background.

Last step is to delete this function from wx_EVENT_TABLE

Comment: this is perfectly understandable. You are NOT using the `sink` parameter in Bind() at all, so wxWidgets has no idea who will handle the event. I'm surprised the code is actually works. BTW, why do you interuse Bind() and Connect()?